# Type literal from object value

Tags: typescript

Got an object of countries like this:

```
const countries = {
  AD: {
    name: "Andorra",
    native: "Andorra",
    phone: "376",
    continent: "EU",
    capital: "Andorra la Vella",
    currency: "EUR",
    languages: [
      "ca"
    ],
    emoji: "",
    emojiU: "U+1F1E6 U+1F1E9"
  },
  AE: {
    name: "United Arab Emirates",
    native: "دولة الإمارات العربية المتحدة",
    phone: "971",
    continent: "AS",
    capital: "Abu Dhabi",
    currency: "AED",
    languages: [
      "ar"
    ],
    emoji: "",
    emojiU: "U+1F1E6 U+1F1EA"
  },
...
```

I can derive a typescript literal union type for the keys like:

```
type CountryIsoCode = keyof typeof countries
// "AD" | "AE" | "AF" | "AG" | "AI" …
```

How can I get a type literal union of the country name values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A big problem is that the countries are typed as

```
{
  name: string,
  native: string,
  // ...
```

with only `string`, and not the names themselves. If you annotate the array `as const`, then the objects inside won't be widened - and the rest is trivial.

Just look up the `CountryIsoCode` on the countries type, and then you can navigate to the `["name"]`.

```
const countries = {
  AD: {
    name: "Andorra",
    native: "Andorra",
    phone: "376",
    continent: "EU",
    capital: "Andorra la Vella",
    currency: "EUR",
    languages: [
      "ca"
    ],
    emoji: "",
    emojiU: "U+1F1E6 U+1F1E9"
  },
  AE: {
    name: "United Arab Emirates",
    native: "دولة الإمارات العربية المتحدة",
    phone: "971",
    continent: "AS",
    capital: "Abu Dhabi",
    currency: "AED",
    languages: [
      "ar"
    ],
    emoji: "",
    emojiU: "U+1F1E6 U+1F1EA"
  },
] as const;
type Countries = typeof countries;
type CountryIsoCode = keyof Countries;
type CountryNames = Countries[CountryIsoCode]["name"];
```

Comment: Thanks very much. There's no way to rebuild countries like: `countriesAsConst = { ...countries } as const` or something and have it work?

Comment: Unfortunately no, you have to type the `as const` at the same place the original object with the data is initialized. Related discussion: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10195 I'd love it if there was a tsconfig option to have everything default to `as const`, without widening, but it doesn't exist, unfortunately